# Setting an Authorization Header in Django without the use of a client

Tags: django, authentication, http-headers, authorization

Is there a way possible to set a header in the server and not from the client?
Probably an example will be me trying to set an Authorization Header with a token to the server and not from the client because the client can't access that token as it's made with a httponly cookie.

Tried something in a Django view.

```
request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = f'Token {....}'
```

And it works in the sense that I can see that key and value in the header but for some reasons it seems not to work as it should be like using a client will this logic will make the request an authenticated one, but doing this from the server doesn't seem to do that..

It's like it's tricking me to believe it works by showing me the object in the header, but there is no functionality of it.

*EDIT*
view.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def createView(request, *args, **kwargs):
     token = request.COOKIES.get('token')
     request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']=f'Token {token}'
     print(request.users)
     print(request.headers)
     #to see what's coming through
     serializer = TweetPostSerializer(data=request.data)
     if serializer.is_valid():
          serializer.save(user=request.user)
          return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
     return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: can you share your view and curl

Comment: I'm not using curl as I have a Js Frontend already. And I will share the view as well

Comment: Can you share more details like view and URLs?

Comment: I have edited the post with the views .. and also I'm using a n httponly cookie with the token and it's working fine there .. just that after setting the headers on the server with that line of code, it doesn't seem to function as it should like setting the headers even tho it shows me the headers correctly, it just doesn't function like the request should be authenticated. It's as if it's setting the Authorization Header but not doing it's functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in a middleware and put it into the list of middlewares in your settings.py, before the AuthenticationMiddleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'myproject.myapps.myapp.middleware.MyAuthorizationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Where `myproject.myapps.myapp.middleware.MyAuthorizationMiddleware`:

```
class MyAuthorizationMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('token')
        if token:
            request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']=f'Token {token}'
        return self.get_response(request)
```

To understand why you need to do it like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Hey thanks for this, you a life saver!. But a question included , can't I make this middleware work for only a view like a the way mixins work.. because it seems to work for all views and with that I won't be able to create the token/cookie in the first place coz that view will need to be authorized as well to do that. So will it be possible to ensure it works for me views and not all the views

Comment: @HarrisonAustinOsagiede I have added a check for the token. This will then only set the  auth header if the cookie is present, and will be a noop for any other requests.